# How do I make my background repeat-x as a bottom header on my website?

Tags: css, background, styles, stylesheet

Right now I am using the following code to place a navigation pane at the bottom of my website, but it is showing a line at the top of the page:

--CSS (Internal)--

```
<head>
  <style>
    body.main
     {
       background: url('images/bindingdark_small.png') repeat-x bottom left;
     }
  </style>
</head>


<body class="main">
</body>
```

Comment: Is there something in your body (or your CSS) that would give it any height? As it stands, your body will be empty, and that "line" is a few pixels of your repeating image across whatever padding/etc. is in the empty `body`.

Comment: Can you provide us a link? Maybe the background-image in not big enought. Try to add 'background-size: auto 100%;'

Answer (score 0):

I think 2 things could be happening:

1. Like Paul Roub said in the comments, if your body.main is empty then your line is the result of your image repeating itself.
2. Maybe you need to add some padding-top in order to increase the heigh of your background. Add some padding to it and test if it results in the way you are expecting to be.

I hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

The reason why is it showing at the top of your page is because your page is actually empty. Check the height value of your `body` element. Its `height: 0px;`.

Fill the content on your page, or add static value to your body, eg.:

```
body {
    height: 1000px
}
```

Not sure if you will like this solution. But i have a better idea. For example - add a `footer` tag inside `body`, and declare following values:

```
footer {
    width:100%;
    height:40px;
    position:absolute;
    bottom:0px;
    background: url('images/bindingdark_small.png') repeat-x bottom left;
}
```

It will stick to the bottom of the page regardless of your content and body `height`. Hope it helps.